# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite

Using SQLite 1.0.66 with NHibernate 3 in .NET 4.0 show this error:

Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver.

I tryed:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
</startup>
```

Tryed to copy manually the files to debug folder.

Any help?

Tks[]

Patrick Coelho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using win7-64bit maybe this is a 32bit/64bit verion problem of System.Data.SQLite.DLL.

Does your program work if you compile it as 32bitOnly and using the 32bit version of System.Data.SQLite.DLL?

Comment: Thanks. I solved with <property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">none</property>

Comment: where you add / put this property?

Comment: forcing my test assembly to use 32bit worked for this version of Sqlite. have done this in the past but forgot and this helped me find the answer. thanks!

Comment: Or x64 if on a 64-bit operating system/machine.